# Flex - ComboBox has lines around it

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, flex-spark

I'm stumbling my way through designing my first Flex app, using Flex Builder 4 Beta 2. I'm trying to use a ComboBox, but they always seem to have lines around it and I can't figure out how to get rid of them.

All I did was drag the ComboBox from the Controls section in the Design section of the UI onto the screen.  I haven't changed any settings, no special css, just used the default ComboBox and this is what I get.

Any ideas?

Comment: Compile the SWF and view it in a browser. I suspect that is just an ide error.

Comment: That is how it looks in the browser. In the IDE, the dropdown box looks fine (but it's not open in the IDE, which is when the lines show up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a bug in the beta. Now that the full version is out, we've upgraded to Flash Builder 4 Premium and I no longer see this problem.